# Error: The page has been destroyed and can no longer be used

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing an add-on for the first time. It puts a little widget in the status bar that displays the number of unread Google Reader items. To accommodate this, the add-on process queries the Google Reader API every minute and passes the response to the widget. When I run `cfx test` I get this error:

> Error: The page has been destroyed and can no longer be used.

I made sure to catch the widget's `detach` event and stop the refresh timer in response, but I'm still seeing the error. What am I doing wrong? Here's the relevant code:

```
// main.js - Main entry point
const tabs = require('tabs');
const widgets = require('widget');
const data = require('self').data;
const timers = require("timers");
const Request = require("request").Request;

function refreshUnreadCount() {
    // Put in Google Reader API request
    Request({
        url: "https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?output=json",
        onComplete: function(response) {
            // Ignore response if we encountered a 404 (e.g. user isn't logged in)
            // or a different HTTP error.
            // TODO: Can I make this work when third-party cookies are disabled?
            if (response.status == 200) {
                monitorWidget.postMessage(response.json);
            } else {
                monitorWidget.postMessage(null);
            }
        }
    }).get();
}

var monitorWidget = widgets.Widget({
    // Mandatory widget ID string
    id: "greader-monitor",

    // A required string description of the widget used for
    // accessibility, title bars, and error reporting.
    label: "GReader Monitor",
    contentURL: data.url("widget.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.7.2.min.js"), data.url("widget.js")],

    onClick: function() {
        // Open Google Reader when the widget is clicked.
        tabs.open("https://www.google.com/reader/view/");
    },

    onAttach: function(worker) {
        // If the widget's inner width changes, reflect that in the GUI
        worker.port.on("widthReported", function(newWidth) {
            worker.width = newWidth;
        });

        var refreshTimer = timers.setInterval(refreshUnreadCount, 60000);

        // If the monitor widget is destroyed, make sure the timer gets cancelled.
        worker.on("detach", function() {
            timers.clearInterval(refreshTimer);
        });

        refreshUnreadCount();
    }
});
```

---

```
// widget.js - Status bar widget script

// Every so often, we'll receive the updated item feed. It's our job
// to parse it.
self.on("message", function(json) {
    if (json == null) {
        $("span#counter").attr("class", "");
        $("span#counter").text("N/A");
    } else {
        var newTotal = 0;
        for (var item in json.unreadcounts) {
            newTotal += json.unreadcounts[item].count;
        }

        // Since the cumulative reading list count is a separate part of the
        // unread count info, we have to divide the total by 2.
        newTotal /= 2;
        $("span#counter").text(newTotal);

        // Update style
        if (newTotal > 0)
            $("span#counter").attr("class", "newitems");
        else
            $("span#counter").attr("class", "");
    }

    // Reports the current width of the widget
    self.port.emit("widthReported", $("div#widget").width());
});
```

**Edit**: I've uploaded the project in its entirety to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/pieterdd/GoogleReaderMonitor).

Comment: This error comes to your postMessage. Have you tried with `monitorWidget.port.emit("widthReported", response.json);` ?

Comment: @Charles: I was able to fix the issue because of your comment. Could you post this as an answer so that you're eligible for the bounty?

Comment: Yes I do it now but I can't give more explanation :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you use the method `monitorWidget.port.emit("widthReported", response.json);` you can fire the event. It the second way to communicate with the content script and the add-on script.

- [Reference for the port communication](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html)
- [Reference for the communication with postMessage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-postmessage.html)

Comment: Thanks again, the bounty is yours!

Comment: For future reference, I'll add a link to [Timing Issues Using postMessage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-postmessage.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this message comes up when you call `monitorWidget.postMessage()` in `refreshUnreadCount()`. The obvious cause for it would be: while you make sure to call `refreshUnreadCount()` only when the worker is still active, this function will do an asynchronous request which might take a while. So by the time this request completes the worker might be destroyed already.

One solution would be to pass the worker as a parameter to `refreshUnreadCount()`. It could then add its own `detach` listener (remove it when the request is done) and ignore the response if the worker was detached while the request was performed.

```
function refreshUnreadCount(worker) {
    var detached = false;
    function onDetach()
    {
        detached = true;
    }
    worker.on("detach", onDetach);

    Request({
        ...
        onComplete: function(response) {
            worker.removeListener("detach", onDetach);
            if (detached)
                return;  // Nothing to update with out data

            ...
        }
    }).get();
}
```

Then again, using `try..catch` to detect this situation and suppress the error would probably be simpler - but not exactly a clean solution.

Comment: Updated main.js here: http://pastebin.com/Eiti2Nss I'm still getting the error after running `cfx test`. I haven't read about thread safety in Firefox add-on programming yet, it's on my todo list.

Comment: @Pieter: There is no thread safety, JavaScript is single-threaded - unless you create a DOM worker explicitly (totally unrelated to the page workers you have in the SDK).

Comment: So I only need to be careful with asynchronous requests and timers? According to http://pastebin.com/ccx80iJV, a call to `monitorWidget.postMessage(null)` is still causing problems.

Comment: @Pieter: How about sending the message to the specific worker only? `worker.postMessage(null)`? From your stack trace, looks like there is some issue with the widget's management of active views.

Comment: I [replaced](http://pastebin.com/PpNtfiAv) the `monitorWidget.postMessage` calls with `worker.postMessage` calls. The error [persists](http://pastebin.com/3FDMhPEN). I'm afraid I'm not yet familiar with some of the terminology you're using. I tried searching for [active views](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=widget+"active+views"+site:addons.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdevelopers) in the documentation but I couldn't find it. Are there any relevant articles/tutorials/docs I'm not aware of that I should read?

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen your message on irc, thanks for reporting your issues.
You are facing some internal bug in the SDK. I've opened a bug about that [here](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/).

You should definitely keep the first version of your code, where you send messages to the widget, i.e. `widget.postMessage` (instead of `worker.postMessage`). Then we will have to fix the bug I linked to in order to just make your code work!!

Then I suggest you to move the setInterval to the toplevel, otherwise you will fire multiple interval and request, one per window. This `attach` event is fired for each new firefox window.

Comment: If I move the refresh timer to the top level, could it start firing before the widget is successfully attached? And if I revert back to the first version, could `refreshUnreadCount()` find itself in a situation where the `Request` is filed, the widget is destroyed and then the `onComplete` handler tries to call `widget.postMessage`, which is no longer available? I don't know how threading impacts add-ons, so I don't really know what would happen. `main.js` would look like [this](http://pastebin.com/MXEz4hnm) after the updates.